# Angular CSS mat-icon-button calc() setting auto increase and decrease with min max

Tags: css, angular-material

I am implementing mat-button in  my css to use calc() to auto increase or decrease the font-size

When I first add the .mat-icon-button without calc(),

at max, I use font-size: 1.5vw. When the window resizes or container width is resized to a smaller width, I like font-size: 0.75vw

```
.mat-button {
  ...
  font-size: font-size: 1.5vw;
}
```

I have many buttons and of course the crowded look appears as the container width is shrunken.

I looked up If I can use conditional inside CSS but no luck. Then I tried calc() like so

```
.mat-button {
  ...
  font-size: calc(100%);
}
```

Made progress and the button width and height will shrink according to the container size

But the font-size is too small and the buttons are too tiny. Not a great UX experience

I am looking up if I can do min and max in CSS button but the min is not working

```
.mat-button {
  ...
  font-size: min(calc(100%), 2rem);
}
```

I was thinking in CSS I can do min/max like the following but no luck so far

```
.mat-button {
  ...
  font-size: min(max(calc(100%), 2rem), 1rem);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This can be done best using media query, so you can set the font size according to your needs. like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

if you need a more precise size, you will need to use SASS for adding conditional to your styling.